# Universal Hashing Integers

Tags: hash, universal

This is my first thread here and I would like to ask you a couple of questions for universal hashing of integers.
A universal hashing algorithm is supposed to use this:

```
equation =
((a*x+b)mod p) mod m

a=random number from 1 to p-1

b=random number from 0 to p-1

x= the Key 

p= a prime number >=m

m=the size of the array
```

I know the numbers I am going to hash are on the range of 1-2969.
But I cannot understand how to use this equation in order to make as low collisions as possible.
At the time a and b are random I cannot do anything about it.
My question is how I am supposed to pick the prime if I have more than one choice, the range of primes I can use are from 2 to 4999.
I tried to pick the first available that corresponds the requirements for the function but sometimes it can return negative numbers. I have searched on Google and Stackoverflow but I could not figure out what I am not doing wrong.

I am coding in C. Also, I can use only universal hashing.

Thank your for your time.

Comment: How did you get your prime values for p? Basically, what I am asking is if you trust them, as `x`, and `p-1` look like they could be the easiest to become negative by mistake. You should generate a whole bunch, and then for any negative ones print out a, b, x, p, and m to check which value seems to be the problem.

Comment: The prime numbers are being picked from an array given by the professor.The array includes all primes from 2 to 4999.I generate a and b so they are positive Numbers.X is always positive.

Comment: Alright, well `((a*x+b) % p) % m` will always be positive, given that `{a, x, b, p, m}` contains all positive integers as well. Either one of those variables is getting the wrong value, or you implemented the math incorrectly. Could you post your C code so that we can better inspect for errors. I am not very familiar with the theory for universal hashing with integers (in my experience, integers can be hashed as themselves), but I can say that the process you posted will never be negative with all positive arguments. If you post your code I will try to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I solved it i had to make sure that p was not equal to m cause the number that was produced made collisions so i just have to find the prime number that is the next higher from the biggest integer i have to hash. Thank you for your time.